# Bandwidth usage monitoring

Tags: software-rec, monitoring, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out network traffic per IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36815/find-out-network-traffic-per-ip)

I want to monitor my bandwidth usuage for wired as well wireless devices on my network.

Is there any tool, preferably one that does not use a master or agent concept or requires `snmp` on every device I want to monitor?

I was searching and found `ntop` but it is not good enough as it has many limitations.

Comment: At the moment this is a duplicate of the question that says to use `ntop`; what are you looking for that it can't do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IPtraf or Bmon ? I believe they don't require snmp to be installed.Tools like Cacti or Zenoss can provide a best monitoring but they require snmp to be installed in each machine .

Comment: but IPTRAF and BMON can monitor only the monitor traffic for individual ip but nt for the whole network  I m not sure though..??????

Comment: Iptraf or bmon lets you to analyse traffic following in and out of your server .So in your case ,I suggest you to use zenoss or Cacti.I have been working with them for long time .They provide excellent monitoring .

Comment: the problem is that i cant maunally install snmp in each  device I wnt to monitor So zenoss n cacti have limitations. Ntop do not have that limitation but in Ntop Ips keep fluctuating and it mainly captures the its configured system data only , thats why I was asking

Comment: Most Remote server monitoring tool requires an agent or SNMP .I guess those things  wont work for you :) . For some tools ,they can work without agent or snmp ,but for them you would require to give SSH access .Tools like kSar which works on sar can get data of remote server via SSH .KSysGuard is also kDE based tool which works in similar way.Try the Ksar ! and connect with SSH .You might need sar and jdk to be installed .